# How to access an element in a fragment from another activity

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment, and this fragment has a button (in fragment_call.xml) and is called by Simple Call Activity.

```
class SimpleCallActivity : CallFragment.OnCallEvents {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivitySimpleCallBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_simple_call).also {
            binding = it
        }
```

Activity_simple_call

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/call_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment_call

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_call_disconnect"/>
```

CallFragment class

```
class CallFragment : Fragment() {
interface OnCallEvents {
    fun onCallHangUp()
    fun onToggleMic(): Boolean
} 
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
    DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentCallBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_call, container, false).also {

    ...

    binding.buttonCallDisconnect.setOnClickListener({

        callEvents.onCallHangUp()
    })
}
```

How can I access this button element from another class? It says null when I access it directly with

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_call.*

button_call_disconnect.callOnClick();
```

Comment: So where are you inflating `item_contact.xml`?

Comment: sorry my fault. the button is in fragment_call.xml.